# How to call Objective-C function in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop

I am trying to call an old Objective-C function from Swift. Bridging Header file is OK

This the Objective-C function ;

```
- (void) writeBytes:(const UInt8 *)bytes length:(int)length {
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        byteQueue->put((char)*bytes++);
    }
}
```

And my swift codes ;

```swift
var generator: FSKSerialGenerator = FSKSerialGenerator()

@IBOutlet weak var txtf: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

@IBAction func btnyaz(sender: UIButton) {

    generator.writeBytes(txtf, UTF8Char)

}
```

Error is :

> Cannot invoke 'writeBytes' with an argument list of type '(UITextField!, UTF8Char.Type)'

Comment: Please don't tag spam, if your question is about obj-c and swift, then don't tag C & C++.

Comment: The first parameter to the `writeBytes` method is `const UInt8 *` yet you try to pass in a `UITextField`. Those aren't anywhere near close to the same thing.

Comment: @GkNx What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to obtain the pointer address of the text field?

Comment: i am so sorry @Borgleader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txtf` is a `UITextField`. What you *probably* want is to pass the text contents of this field as an array of UTF-8 bytes to the
`writeBytes()` method.

This can be achieved with

```
let utf8 = Array(txtf.text.utf8)
generator.writeBytes(utf8, length: Int32(utf8.count))
```

(The `Int32()` conversion is necessary because the C type `int` is mapped
to `Int32` in Swift, not to `Int`.)

If `writeBytes()` expects a NUL-terminated array of UTF-8 bytes then
you can use

```
let utf8 = Array(txtf.text.nulTerminatedUTF8)
```

instead.